# The completion functionality

Tags: python, web-scraping, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm a total noob in programming, I'm writing a web scraping program, and I've encountered a problem - I can't implement the functionality to terminate the program. I need to make it so that when the 'Finish Parsing' button is pressed, the parsing() script stops. Here's the code:

```
@dp.message_handler(state=ParsingState.input)
async def handle_name_input(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    try:
        from KeyBoardButton import exit_parsing_markup
        from parsing_main import query, parsing, limit_count_ads
        await state.update_data(name_input=message.text)
        data = await state.get_data()
        count_ads = data['count_ads']
        name_input = data['name_input']
        await ParsingState.next()
        await message.answer("Parsing started!!!", reply_markup=exit_parsing_markup)
        url = query(name_input)
        limit_ads = limit_count_ads(count_ads)
        chat_id = message.chat.id
        await parsing(url, chat_id, bot, limit_ads)

    except Exception as e:
        await message.answer("Something went wrong")

@dp.message_handler(state=ParsingState.exit_menu)
async def handle_parsing_exit(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    if message.text == "Finish parsing":
        await message.answer(text="Great, the parser has been stopped")
        await state.reset_data()
        await handle_inline_marketplace_markup(message)
    else:
        await message.answer(text="Parsing is already running, you can only finish it if you want")
```

Can such functionality be implemented directly in the Telegram bot file, or do I need to rewrite something in the script itself? Because I don't understand this, if additional code is needed, please let me know, because I really need help. I've been working on this for a long time and tried many things: working with FSMContext, global variables, passing values to the script. I would be grateful for your help.

I tried to create global variables and FSMContext states whose changes in the handle_parsing_exit would terminate the script's execution, in the handle_name_input. However, I was unsuccessful.

Comment: Your question is unclear, what doesn't work? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I need to make it so that when the 'Finish Parsing' button is pressed, the parsing() script stops In the handler handle_name_input